# Forward all requests in in Node.js/Koa server from http://server/api/* to another ip?

Tags: node.js, proxy, httpserver, koa

I'm using Node.js and Koa to build a web server. However, I'd like to merge it with another server located at 192.168.1.5:80. How can I make it so that all requests to {my web server}:80/api/* are exactly the same as requests to 192.168.1.5:80/api/*.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You could use koa-proxy:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/koa-proxy

Then for the proxy, your code could look like this:

```
var koa = require('koa');
var proxy = require('koa-proxy');
var app = koa();
app.use(proxy({
    host:  'http://192.168.1.5', // proxy to 192.168.1.5:80... 
    match: /^\/api\//        // ...just the /api routes 
}));
app.listen(80);
```

hope that helps ... (not testet)

Comment: Wow! That was easy! Thanks a lot!